# Download a file which is present in newly created directory in a webserver

Tags: linux, shell, curl, download, wget

I am trying to automate a task where i have to everytime download a new file from updated location which is present inside in directory "mydirectory" on a webserver and the directory structure is like this

http://mydirectory/**ABC1/ABC1.tar.gz**

and after sometimes a new file will created and will be present inside "mydirectory" folder in linux webserver

http://mydirectory/**ABC2/ABC2.tar.gz**

Now i a need to download this ABC*.tar.gz file while on every new release of this file

**NOTE :** The parent directory of file is same file name up "." (dot) point.

I tried the samething with this code:

```
echo "Please enter file version: "
read FILE_VER
echo "You entered: $FILE_VER"
echo download $FILE_VER patch to install then type yes/no  :
read CON_VAR
if["CON_VAR"="yes"];then
        echo Your patch is being downloaded...
        curl -o output_curl http://<hostname>/5.0.4/USG_5.0_$input_variable__Actiance64bit/USG_5.0_$input_variable_Actiance64bit.tar.gz .
        exit
else
        echo "You made a right choice or you are drunk :) "
fi
```

Can anyone suggest me what i am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

1. You aren't setting `$input_variable` in the script you have shown here.
2. If you're setting `$input_variable` somewhere else then make sure to use it as `${input_variable}` since it is followed by underscore in your code and that is considered part of of variable name if not used in the form of `${input_variable}`.

Answer (score 0):

Shell syntax is very whitespace sensitive. This

```
if["CON_VAR"="yes"];then
```

needs to look like this

```
if [ "$CON_VAR" = "yes" ];then
```

The brackets are not just syntax: `[` is actually a command (it's the `test` command) and needs to be separated both from the `if` command and it's subsequent arguments by whitespace. Also, the `test` command does different things depending on how many arguments it gets.